# Allow '+' sign on HTML form type="number"

Tags: html, forms

So if I set the type of a form to number, HTML does not accept as input a number with the plus sign (+12). But it does accept a number with the negative sign (-12). Is it possible to make it accept the plus sign?

Comment: you can use pattern attribute and declare regular expression for it like this pattern='[\+]\d{2}[\(]\d{2}[\)]\d{4}[\-]\d{4}'

Answer (score 9):

`+12` is not a number, but `-12` is. Your only option is changing it to `type="text"`. You can't trust frontend validation anyways and there are always other methods (regex, etc) to verifying that the string in an input is a number. This example is HTML 5 and only supported on IE 10+ (same as `type="number"`).

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" pattern="[-+]?\d*" />
    <input type="submit" value="Test" />
</form>
```

Comment: This is not a helpful answer in general terms since it doesn't answer the question. I am also in a situation where I need to allow "+" in a telephone-number. While you're right that one cannot trust front-end validation, which I don't, it is somewhat important to use the type "number" if you're trying to make a flawless UX for mobile-users, since it will trigger the number-keypad on their phones. So basically the problem for me is that I want it to not do any validation at all from front-end. The "novalidation" attribute on the form tag doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: @MahNas92 if that's your goal (which isn't what was asked in the question), use [`inputmode="numeric"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-inputmode).

Comment: @Sam thanks for the suggestion but `inputmode="numeric"` also takes text as input.. I want plus(+) and numbers to the input field. any suggestion would be helpful

Comment: You should not use `type="number"` for telephone numbers, they're not really numbers. They're text that happens to use mostly digits, but there are other characters like `+`, `-`, `()` allowed.