# Why can't jQuery get the value of an input type number if it contains a `+`?

Tags: jquery, html

Using the following Html Element:

```
<input type="number" id="numberField" placeholder="number">
```

if you get fill the input with `+16762634` for example.
It will not ge tthe value.

Why is that?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/snga6p1c/)

Comment: its working fine, it gives `+16762634`, what you expect?

Comment: "+" is not a number. So depending on your browser, the rest is not evaluated

Comment: It isn't a number.  You have to strip out any non numeric characters that aren't a single decimal point, thousands separators, or symbols that indicate scientific notation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32259085/2278598 This solution might work for you

Comment: Interestingly, in IE it does get the number including the plus sign. I guess it's that your browser doesn't recognise it as being a number, because "+" isn't a digit. My solution would be to change the field into a normal `input type="text"`

Answer (score 2):

"+" is not a number. So depending on your browser, the rest is not evaluated