# Input type "Number" removes value of my Text field

Tags: php, html

I wanted my `text field` to accept only `numbers` so I try to use HTML5 attribute using "number". But it removes the value inside my `text field`. here is my code

```html
 <div class="form-wrapper-full-width form-wrapper">
   <div class="form-label">
     Company Business Number:
   </div>   
   <div class="form-info">
       <input type="number" name="business_number" title="Business Number" value="<?=$phone_num['business_number']?>">
   </div> 
 </div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18156861/4248328

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML Text Input allow only Numeric input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that a value is set to `$phone_num['business_number']`? And are you sure that `$phone_num['business_number']` **contains only numbers**?

If it is set just try removing short tags of PHP.

```
<div class="form-wrapper-full-width form-wrapper">
   <div class="form-label">
        Company Business Number:
   </div>           
   <div class="form-info">
       <input type="number" name="business_number" title="Business Number" value="<?php echo $phone_num['business_number']; ?>">
   </div>   
 </div>
```

Comment: yea it's the problem, it's contains  "+" sign that's why it's becoming blank. how can I solve that?

Comment: You have to use patterns. There is a answer in this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32259058/allow-sign-on-html-form-type-number

Comment: Check this also. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: thanks, honestly those link didn't solve my problem, but you help me to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Its not **removing** your value but you forgot to **echo** your value and thats why it showing blank. **echo your value**.

> Make sure your value must be a number if it contains any special
>   character or anything apart from number then it will remove that value
>   and shows blank.

Try **below code:**

```
<div class="form-wrapper-full-width form-wrapper">
   <div class="form-label">
        Company Business Number:
   </div>           
   <div class="form-info">
       <input type="number" name="business_number" title="Business Number" value="<?php echo $phone_num['business_number']; ?>">
   </div>   
 </div>
```

Comment: No. He has not forget to echo the value because `<?=$phone_num['business_number']?>` is equal to `<?php echo $phone_num['business_number']; ?>`.

Comment: @Ranuka if short tags of php not allowed from php.ini then definetelly it will not works and thats why i have write echo the value which you are getting. hope it clears to you i guess.

Answer (score 1):

Using Javascript you can remove text and can keep numbers.

```
<?php
    $business_number = "100ww";
?>
<div class="form-wrapper-full-width form-wrapper">
<div class="form-label">
    Company Business Number:
</div>          
<div class="form-info">
    <input type="text" id="business_number" name="business_number" title="Business Number" value="<?=$business_number?>">
</div>  
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function changeIt(){
    var val = document.getElementById('business_number').value;
    number = val.replace(/\D/g,'');
    document.getElementById('business_number').value = number;
}
changeIt()
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First check any js aur css apply on your input fields also check short tag is allow in your php.ini configuration.